# MySQL get value from string with char_length()

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have a column that consists of details of an orderline named 'ConcatValue'. An example of a value in this column is:

```
573856014/100/M00558640/OrderQty12
```

I want to extract the order value which can be founded after 'OrderQty'. I thought I had a solution by executing the following statement: `substr(ConcatValue,char_length(ConcatValue)-1,char_length(ConcatValue))`

This results in only level the last 2 characters of the string from the column ConcatValue. For the ConcatValue mentioned above I will get the following result: '12'. Which is the desired result.
But when the orderline has an Order quantity below 10, for example in the following ConcatValue:`573856014/100/M00558640/OrderQty3`

I will get the following result: `y3`

My question: Is there a way to delete 'y' if a row has an y within the value? Or is there a way to replace the y with a 0? Or is there a way to only select the last digits from the ConcatValue string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string functions.
With [`substring_index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) you can get the last part of the string and with [`replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) remove `'OrderQty'`:

```
select replace(
         substring_index(ConcatValue, '/', -1),
         'OrderQty',
         ''
       )
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the simplest method is simply:

```
select substring_index(ConcatValue, 'OrderQty', -1)
```